# Trying to change the class of a dynamic group of columns from char to time in R

Tags: r, class

I am loading a reference table into R that has a group of columns that are times (hh:mm) .  First issue is that R sees them as double and not times.  I know I can individually tell R that these columns are times, but the number of columns that need to change to time is dynamic.  They are always grouped together so I can easily tell R the range of columns.  To make things "easier" I have brought in all columns as character, although if there is a solution where I do not need to do that, it would be great.

```
RefSF <- read_csv(datapathSF, col_types = cols(.default = "c"))
```

I have told R what the column range is both in names and index.

```
ref.SF <- as.data.table(RefSF)
ref.Sta <- as.data.table(RefSta)

SFCCount <- as.integer(ncol(ref.SF)) -1
SFMetal <-  as.integer(which(colnames(ref.SF) == "Metal")) + 1
SFSta1 <- colnames(ref.SF)[SFMetal]
SFStaL <- colnames(ref.SF)[SFCCount]
StCol <- list(SFMetal:SFCCount)
StColNam <- list(colnames(ref.SF)[SFMetal:SFCCount])
```

The above code creats these two lists.

```
> StCol
[[1]]
 [1] 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52

> StColNam
[[1]]
 [1] "ATL" "AUS" "BOS" "CDG" "CLT" "CUN" "DCA" "DEN" "DFW" "EWR" "EZE" "FLL" "FRA" "GIG" "GRU" "JFK" "LAS" "LAX" "LGA" "LHR" "MCO" "MEX"
[23] "MIA" "NRT" "ORD" "PHL" "PHX" "PIT" "RDU" "SAN" "SAT" "SCL" "SEA" "SFO" "SJU" "STL" "TPA" "TUL"
```

The fields are filled with times (i.e. 06:30) or are NA.

I have tried to loop through the column range as change the class from char to time.  Individually, this code works, but it is not working in the loop.

```
for (Sta in names(StColNam)){
  ref.SF[[Sta]] <- strptime(ref.SF[Sta], format = "%H:%M")
  ref.SF[[Sta]] <- as.POSIXlt(ref.SF[Sta])
}
```

The code appears to run through with no errors, but the class has not changed.
(ATL is the first column name in the range)

```
> class(ref.SF$ATL)
[1] "character"
```

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Can you add some sample data to your question?

Comment: data has been added.